# finding first item in a list whose first item in a tuple is matched

Tags: python

I have a list of several thousand unordered tuples that are of the format

```
(mainValue, (value, value, value, value))
```

Given a main value (which may or may not be present), is there a '**nice**' way, other than iterating through every item looking and incrementing a value, where I can produce a list of indexes of tuples that match like this:

```
index = 0;
for destEntry in destList:
if destEntry[0] == sourceMatch:
    destMatches.append(index)
index = index + 1
```

So I can compare the sub values against another set, and remove the best match from the list if necessary.
This works fine, but just seems like python would have a better way!

Edit:
As per the question, when writing the original question, I realised that I could use a dictionary instead of the first value (in fact this list is within another dictionary), but after removing the question, I still wanted to know  how to do it as a tuple.

Comment: So do you really mean tuple? Cause you have it shown as a list

Comment: When you say "unordered", do you mean a match is any tuple that has those 4 values? So is ```(1,2,3,4)``` a match with ```(4,3,2,1)```?

Comment: Can you provide insight into your goal? You might be better served using different data structures.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it as a list, I meant a tuple.

Comment: By undorderd I mean the first value are unordered. The 4 values in the the tuples are large floating point values that are compared with another set of 4 floating point values to work out the closest value. I just want a list that match the first value so I can do this comparison elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With list comprehension your `for` loop can be reduced to this expression:

```
destMatches = [i for i,destEntry in enumerate(destList) if destEntry[0] == sourceMatch]
```

You can also use [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=filter%20built#filter)<sup>1</sup> built in function to filter your data:

```
destMatches = filter(lambda destEntry:destEntry[0] == sourceMatch, destList)
```

<sub>**1**: In Python 3 `filter` is a class and returns a `filter object`.</sub>